# optimal solution for expected absolute loss function

Tags: probability, machine-learning

I need to calculate the optimal solution $f(x)$ for the expected absolute loss function, anyone know how to solve it? thank you so much!

let's consider a similar problem first:
for squared loss function
$$loss(f(x), y) = (f(x) - y)^2$$
the expected loss function would be
$$E[loss(f(x),y)] = \int\int (f(x)-y)^2 p(x,y)\ \ dx\ \ dy$$

To minimize the expected loss function, we can do as the following way:
$$\int\int (f(x)-y)^2 p(x,y)\ \ dx\ \ dy\\= \int\int\big \{(f(x) - E[y|x])^2+(y-E[y|x])^2
+2(f(x)-E[y|x])(E[y|x]-y)\big\}p(x,y)\ \ dx\ \ dy
$$
Since $$\int\int 2(f(x)-E[y|x])~(E[y|x]-y)~p(x,y)\ \ dx\ \ dy = 0$$
it could be proved that when 
$$f(x)=E[y|x]$$
we will minimize $$E[loss(f(x),y)]$$

now, what if we define?
$$loss(f(x),y) = \big |~f(x)-y~ \big |$$

what would be the optimal  $f(x)$?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I know the answer now.
our goal is to minimize
\begin{align*}
E[\mathfrak{l}(f(x), y)]
&= \int\int |f(x) - y| p(x, y) dx dy\\
&= \int (\int |f(x) - y| p(y|x) dy ) p(x)dx
\end{align*}
as for every $x$, the value of $f(x)$ could be independently chosen,
thus we just need to minimize
$$
\int |f(x) - y| p(y|x) dy
$$
now calculate the derivative of above expression with respect to $f(x)$, and set
it to zero, we have
\begin{align*}
0 = \int sign( f(x) - y )~ p(y|x) dy
&= \int_{f(x)}^{+\infty} p(y|x) dy - \int^{f(x)}_{-\infty} p(y|x) dy\\ 
\end{align*}
which implies
$$
\int_{f(x)}^{+\infty} p(y|x) dy = \int^{f(x)}_{-\infty} p(y|x) dy
$$
which is the condition $f(x)$ must satisfy to minimize $E[\mathfrak{l}(f(x), y)]$

Comment: That is the conditional median.  In general the median minimises the expected absolute loss while the mean minimises the expected squared loss.